# How to compute $\mathbb{P}(B(\tau)\leq a)$, $B(t)$ is standard Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

How to compute $\mathbb{P}(B(\tau)\leq a)$, where $\tau$ ~ Exp(λ), which is independent of $B(t),t\geq 0.$

here is my computation:
$ \mathbb{P}\left(B\left(\tau\right)\le a\right) =\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\left\{ B\left(\tau\right)\le a\right\} }|\tau\right]\right]
 =\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(\tau\right)\le a|\tau=s\right)ds
 =\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(s\right)\le a\right)ds
 =\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{B\left(s\right)}{\sqrt{s}}\le\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)ds
 =\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)ds$.

why we have
$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(\tau\right)\le a|\tau=s\right)ds
 =\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(s\right)\le a\right)ds$ ?

it means that $\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(\tau\right)\le a|\tau=s\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(s\right)\le a\right) \ \ \mathbb{P}_\tau -a.s.$

how to prove $\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(\tau\right)\le a|\tau=s\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(B\left(s\right)\le a\right) \ \ \mathbb{P}_\tau -a.s.$?

Comment: Because $\tau$ is independent of $B(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Comment: You are conditioning on the null event $\tau=s$?

Comment: it is well defined by measure theory@user10354138

Comment: I just want to prove it rigoriously.@Surb

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to more general result. Namely:

**Theorem** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal F$ a sub-$\sigma-$field. Let $X:\Omega \to (E_1,\mathcal E_1)$ and $Y: \Omega \to (E_2,\mathcal E_2)$ be random variables (where $(E_i,\mathcal E_i)$ are some let's say polish spaces). Assume that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ whereas $Y$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable. Moreover let $F:E_1 \times E_2 \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $\mathbb E[|F(X,Y)|] < \infty$. Then $\mathbb E[F(X,Y)| \mathcal G] = H(Y)$ almost surely, where $H(t) = \mathbb E[F(X,t)]$

**Proof** Take any $A \in \mathcal G$. We need to prove $$ \mathbb E[F(X,Y) 1_A] = \mathbb E[H(Y)1_A] $$ To do this, consider random vector $V=(X,Y,1_A)$ and note that due to independence assumptions, $X$ is independent from $(Y,1_A)$, so that letting $\mu_X,\mu_{(Y,1_A)}$ be respectivelly distributions of $X$ and $(Y,1_A)$ we arrive at $$ \mathbb E[F(X,Y)1_A] = \int_{E_1 \times E_2 \times \mathbb R} F(x,y)z d\mu_{(X,Y,1_A)}(x,y,z) = \int_{E_1}\int_{E_2 \times \mathbb R} F(x,y)z d\mu_X(x)d\mu_{(Y,1_A)}(y,z) = $$ $$ = \int_{E_2 \times \mathbb R} z \int_{E_1} F(x,y) d\mu_X(x) d\mu_{(Y,1_A)}(y,z) = \int_{E_2 \times \mathbb R} z \mathbb E[F(X,y)] d\mu_{(Y,1_A)}(y,z)$$
Where we used Fubinii due to integrability assumptions. Now note that under integral we have our function $H$, hence we showed $$ \mathbb E[F(X,Y)1_A] = \int_{E_2 \times \mathbb R} z H(y) d\mu_{(Y,1_A)}(y,z) = \mathbb E[1_A H(Y)] $$ which proves our theorem.

In your question, you want to use it here: $$ \mathbb E[1_{B(\tau) \le a} | \tau] $$ with $F(B,\tau) = 1_{B(\tau) \le a}$ (we treat here $B$ as a function $\Omega \to C([0,\infty))$ and $\mathcal G = \sigma(\tau)$ getting $$ \mathbb P(B(\tau) \le a) = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[F(B,\tau) | \tau]] = \mathbb E[ H(\tau)] $$ where $H(t) = \mathbb E[F(B,t)] = \mathbb P(B(t) \le a) = \Phi(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}})$. Hence $$ \mathbb P(B(\tau) \le a) = \mathbb E[ \Phi(\frac{a}{\sqrt{\tau}})] = \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \Phi(\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}})dx $$

Edit: Maybe two words why function $F$ is measurable. Note that $F$ is a superposition of $1_{[-\infty,a]}$ which is measurable and function $G:C([0,\infty) \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $G(f,x) = f(x)$. It is not hard to see that $G$ is continuous, hence measurable. Indeed, taking any such $f,x$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ we have for all $g \in C([0,\infty)$ such that $\|f-g\|_{\infty} \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and for all $y \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ for appriopate $\delta$ giving $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ that $$ |G(f,x)-G(g,y)| = |f(x)-g(y)| \le |f(x)-f(y)| + |f(y)-g(y)| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \|f-g\|_{\infty} \le \varepsilon $$

Comment: you are really amazing!! thanks a lot!!